# Changing Dirac Delta to Kronecker Delta?

Tags: programming, fourier-analysis, code-request

I have a program where I actually need Kronecker Delta instead of Dirac Delta Function. Is there a way to make such a switch in *Mathematica 11*.

Example:

```
In[3]:= FourierTransform[Cos[t]^2, t, n, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]

Out[3]= 1/4 DiracDelta[-2 + n] + DiracDelta[n]/2 + 
 1/4 DiracDelta[2 + n]
```

This is not actually the proper use of the `Dirac Delta` but surely of the `Kronecker Delta`.

```
  Table[DiracDelta[2 + n], {n, -3, 0, -1}]
```

Want to use it in this format

```
Table[KroneckerDelta[2 + n], {n, -3, 0, -1}]
```

I want to use it in the above format, whenever I provide any periodic function(here `Cos[t]^2`(for an example), answer should have been `1/4 KroneckerDelta[-2 + n]+ KroneckerDelta[n]/2 + 1/4 KroneckerDelta[2 + n]`). Is there a way out?

It may be outrageously weird question ever asked. But I think *Mathematica* can do this, with your help, surely.

Please forgive me for such questions as I am still new to the Mathematica

Comment: `FourierTransform[Cos[t]^2, t, n, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}] /. 
 DiracDelta[x_] :> KroneckerDelta[x, 0]`?

Comment: @march God bless you. Can you write it in the form of an answer?

Comment: @march It is not working at all the way, it has to work in the new format. see here [Program](http://imgur.com/UnLDZ7a)

Comment: Try writing `M[n_] = 
 FourierTransform[Cos[t]^2, t, n, 
    FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}] ` instead of `M[n_] := 
  FourierTransform[Cos[t]^2, t, n, 
    FourierParameters -> {-1, 
      1}] `. (Use `=` here instead of `:=`.) The problem is that `:=` *delays* the evaluation of the right-hand side until after a number has been put in for `n` inside `FourierTransform`, causing it not to evaluate because that doesn't make sense. Using `=` evaluates the Fourier transform at the time of setting the definition.

Comment: @march But still the problem is not resolving: [your helpful changes](http://imgur.com/BVY3tQX)

Comment: I misread the notebook. The point is that you have to evaluate the `FourierTransform` *before* putting it in the `Table`! Maybe make a new function `ft[n_] = FourierTransform[Cos[t]^2, t, n, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]`, and define `MM[n_] = Table[f[n] ft[n], {n -3, 3}]`.

Comment: @march perfacto, it worked. Set delayed and set is not very clear to me.

Comment: Distinguishing those is important. I suggest reading the documentation about those two functions (`Set` vs `SetDelayed`). In fact, I *always* recommend reading the documentation.

Comment: @march Thanks, surely.

Comment: @march I was wondering, if the `M[n_] = FourierTransform[Cos[t]^2, t, n, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]` still works for numerical case. I mean in case of `Integrate` we go to `NIntegrate`, similarly `NDSolve`. Does this work without any such special definition of `N` in front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using replacement rules:

```
FourierTransform[Cos[t]^2, t, n, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}] /. DiracDelta[x_] :> KroneckerDelta[x, 0]
```